# Use autocomplete light with django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to populate a django table with autocomplete light so that the user can fill in data in the table, which would then be saved (the whole table is in a form tag).  I have the table working to display the existing data and I have the autocomplete working in model forms (well, a team member got that part working), but I don't know how to combine the two.  The docs are a bit of a mystery to me, but maybe if someone could at least point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

I've tried a few random things to combine them, but honestly they were such stabs in the dark that I don't think they're even worth mentioning.

tables.py

```
class ModifyTable(tables.Table):
    name            = tables.LinkColumn('app-view', args=[A('pk')], verbose_name='Name')
    primary_contact    = tables.Column()
    secondary_contact  = tables.Column()
```

autocomplete

```
autocomplete_light.register(Person,
    search_fields=['first_name', 'last_name', 'username'],
    split_words=True,
    autocomplete_js_attributes={'placeholder': 'Find a user',},
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Django-tables2 provides an API to generate data tables in HTML.

Django-autocomplete-light provides a widget that enables autocompletion inputs.

This widget must be used in a [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/). The django Form class will combine your the HTML `<form>` with models used by django-tables2.

However, a Form must be used by a [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) to be repeated for every row in the table. Note that you could consider [modelformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-model-formset-in-a-view) to generate such a formset.

Use a formset and your work is done here ;)

Comment: The places were the user has to enter data involve a fk lookup of 10,000 items.  I want the user to be able to use auto-complete there.

Comment: Oh, you -1'd the one person who was trying to help you, great move :D BTW, I'm the author of django-autocomplete-light and I garantee that autocomplete widgets work in formsets and with lookups of 100 000 or even 1 000 000 items :) Let me know when you improve your question.

Comment: I wasn't trying to insult you.  I am new here and thought that's what I supposed to do.  I thought my question was clear--if I'm wrong, please let me know how I can improve it and I happily will.

Comment: I'm apparently unable to remove the -1 unless you edit your answer somehow.  But I tried.

Comment: To be fair, though, your answer to "How can I use django-tables2 with auto-complete?" didn't involve either django-tables2 or auto-complete.

Comment: Well, you have a table2 table, you have an autcomplete class. But where is your formset ? FEAR NOT: if you don't know what a formset is, my answer has a link to the official documentation on formsets ;)

Comment: Could you post your formset please ? Thanks !

Comment: Hi, are you still "stabbing in the dark" or did you try to use formsets ? Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: The issue's been temporarily tabled (heh) but I will return to it and update the question soon!